# Converting factor to date and time in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have two columns in my dataset that are factors and are on the form "10may2010 5p.m. to 7p.m."

I want R to read the above factor as a date/ time object.

Next, I would like to know if the date-time in column 1 is before the date-time in column 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Your values aren't any sort of standard date/time format. You really have a time range and base R doesn't have data type that supports that natively. You'll have to split it up to a start time/end time pair. Again, since that doesn't look like a standard format, you'll have to parse those values yourself for the necessary pieces. Are all the values *exactly* formatted like that one ie (two digit date, three character month abbreviation, four digit year, space, hour (1-12), (a.m./p.m), space "to" space, hour(1-12), (a.m./p.m.)) ?

Comment: Yes, except 12pm is coded as "noon"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to parse this string into a sequence, but it seems to work okay and should get you moving in the right direction (and I learned a good bit too).

```
x <- gsub("[.]|to ", "", "10may2010 5p.m. to 7p.m.")
s <- strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]]
dts <- strptime(paste(s[1], s[-1]), "%d%b%Y %I%p")
# [1] "2010-05-10 17:00:00 PDT" "2010-05-10 19:00:00 PDT"
seq(dts[1], dts[2], by = "hour")
# [1] "2010-05-10 17:00:00 PDT" "2010-05-10 18:00:00 PDT" 
# [3] "2010-05-10 19:00:00 PDT"
```

Also have a look at the `lubridate` interval class as it might be what you want.

```
library(lubridate)
interval(dts[1], dts[2])
# [1] 2010-05-10 17:00:00 PDT--2010-05-10 19:00:00 PDT
```